# Critical windows service handle shutdown

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

Assume a Window Server with

- running services and
- running console applications

The nature of this software is very critical. Operations take up to a **few minutes** and should **not be terminated**.

How to handle a shutdown of this server? (An Admin want to shutdown/restart the server)

As default there is a time windows of 20s, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/146092 . But I need up to 5min to end a critical transaction.

Answer (score 1):

At least if you are running as a windows service [you can request additional time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) for the current operation.